# How to Angular 2 passing config constants from HTML to Class to recycle classes?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Assume I want to reuse my Angular 2 components, how can I enter config in HTML and pass this to the class? **This might not be hacker proof (changing HTML)!? What is best practice for Angular 2 to instantiate multiple versions of the same class with different config?**

I have 2 problems:

- I get only 1 console output. So that means the class is static?
- The console output i get is null.

So:

```
<my-comp showWhat="INCOMING"></my-comp>
<my-comp showWhat="OUTGOING"></my-comp>
```

***How to pass INCOMING/OUTGOING to the constructor?***

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-comp'
    [..]
})

  export class MyComponent {
      constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
          console.log("Constructing an instance: showWhat for this instance = "+elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('showWhat'));
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs

Answer (score 0):

using @Input instead

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp'
  [..]

})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() showWhat;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.showWhat);
  }
}
```

use in other component

```
<my-comp showWhat="INCOMING"></my-comp>
<my-comp [showWhat]="someVariable"></my-comp>
```

Documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#inputs-outputs

Live Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/xtnGvdlddU7YCIPV36aN?p=preview

Comment: This does not work in Angular 4. Also I get only once a "undefined" log, but I have multiple <my-comp> in my HTML.